# Hour format in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I am using below statement to display time.

```
Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm:AP")
```

Is it possible to display time in 24 hour Format.
If so how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer following statement display time in 24 hr format:

```
Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"H:m: a")
```

Comment: "a" in the format string should still have am/pm, just lowercase. For normal, i.e. 24 hours a day, formatting, just specify the hours and minutes without any extra. e.g. `hh:mm`